# error in label python, editor pycharm version

Tags: python

I have this:

```
__author__ = 'User'

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Label

class Hello2(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label()

 if __name__=="__main__":
 Hello2().run()
```

But I get an error on this line:

```
return Label()
```

And I dont know why it is an error

[image]
I have it now like this:

```
__author__ = 'User'

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Label

class Hello2(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label()

   if __name__=="__main__":
       Hello2().run()
```

but still the same error

Comment: See image for info

Comment: Your indentation is still wrong. You may benefit from reading http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html. I've updated my answer to give the entire code snippet with the correct indentation.

Comment: Please don't use images to show errors. Run your scripts from the command line. The problem is not where you editor is telling you it is. The problem is the `if` statement. If you run the script from the command line, Python will point to the correct line of the error. In my opinion, anyone not familiar with how to run Python scripts from the command line should avoid IDEs until they learn it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong. Try reindenting like this:

```
__author__ = 'User'

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Label

class Hello2(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label()

if __name__=="__main__":
    Hello2().run()
```

Comment: Ah, thank you!! very nice

Comment: You didn't explain where the problem is.